# I don't know how can I solve OpenCV Python problem

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, signal-processing

The original assignment is

```
Use np.array() to generate the following 8-bit image and obtain the result of applying the following mask: 
However, the edges are padded to zero. (cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)

[[10, 20, 40, 50]
 [50, 20, 50, 20]
 [10, 10, 30, 60]
 [20, 40, 60, 70]]

(a) 3x3 average filter
(b) 3x3 gaussian filter, sigmaX=0
(c) If the results of (a) and (b) are M(x,y) and G(x,y), 
    respectively, calculate M(0,0) and G(0,0) and show that 
    they are consistent with the results of (a) and (b).
```

The problem is,

(a) - 3x3 average filter

(b) - 3x3 gaussian filter, sigmaX=0

And the result of (a) is M(x, y) and the result of (b) is G(x, y)

So I should show that M(0, 0) and G(0, 0) are correct.

I wrote code, but I can't solve this problem.

How can I solve this problem ....

The code -

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

src = np.array([[10, 20, 40, 50],
                 [50, 20, 50, 20],
                 [10, 10, 30, 60],
                 [20, 40, 60, 70]], dtype=np.uint8)

dst1 = cv2.blur(src, ksize=(3, 3), borderType=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)
dst2 = cv2.GaussianBlur(src, ksize=(3, 3), sigmaX=0, borderType=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)

print(dst1)
print(dst1[0][0])
print(dst2)
print(dst2[0][0])
print(dst1[0][0] == dst2[0][0])
```

The result -

[image]

M(0, 0) is 11(dst1[0][0]) and G(0, 0) is 13(dst2[0][0])

I mean, I need to make dst1[0][0] and dst2[0][0] match.

but the result does not match.

Sorry for my bad English skill .....

Comment: " show that M(0, 0) and G(0, 0) are correct." -- can you explain a bit better, what that means ? is your assignment, to show, that opencv's implementation is 'correct' ? then you probably need to calculate it manually for a few pixels (do your own convolution !), and show, that you get the same result. anyway, `dst1[0][0] == dst2[0][0]` is a wrong assumption

Comment: your edit does not help. please answer my question: what does 'correct' mean here ? and no, box and gaussian are different  filter kernels, and they should NOT return the same result

Comment: maybe show us your original assignment ?

Comment: @berak Sorry to late. And that's all the explanation

Comment: thanks ! better late, than never ;) and now i'm sure, you misread it. you're supposed to do a *manual* convolution, and show, that you get the same result as opencv's , not that M(0,0)==G(0,0) (which makes no sense at all)

Comment: @berak You are a really really kind person!!!!!! Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's an assignment, so i wont solve it completely for you, but here are some hints:

so, convolution is the sum of a per-element multiplication between your filter kernel and a pixel neighbourhood of the same size.

at 0,0 - given zero padding, the latter looks like this:

```
0.0  0.0  0.0
0.0 10.0 20.0
0.0 50.0 20.0
```

and a 3x3 box kernel looks like this:

```
1.0/9 1.0/9 1.0/9 
1.0/9 1.0/9 1.0/9
1.0/9 1.0/9 1.0/9
```

so, M(0,0) is:

```
1.0/9 *  0.0 + 1.0/9 *  0.0 + 1.0/9 *  0.0 + 
1.0/9 *  0.0 + 1.0/9 * 10.0 + 1.0/9 * 20.0 +
1.0/9 *  0.0 + 1.0/9 * 50.0 + 1.0/9 * 20.0  == 11.11111
```

and you have to show, that M(0,0) == dst1[0,0]

float values used here to avoid rounding issues. please use `np.float32`, not `np.uint8` in your opencv code to achieve the same.

here's the gaussian kernel, hopefully you know, what to do now, good luck ;)

[image]